# Metricbeat to Logstash on a remote server not working

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I am new to elastic stack . I am trying to send metrics from one pc(ubuntu) to another remote server using Metricbeat and logstash. Below are my configuration files,
**metricbeat.yml**

```
metricbeat.modules:

#------------------------------- System Module -------------------------------
- module: system
  metricsets:
    # CPU stats
    - cpu

    # System Load stats
    - load

    # Per CPU core stats
    #- core

    # IO stats
    #- diskio

    # Per filesystem stats
    - filesystem

    # File system summary stats
    - fsstat

    # Memory stats
    - memory

    # Network stats
    - network

    # Per process stats
    - process

    # Sockets (linux only)
    #- socket
  enabled: true
  period: 10s
  processes: ['.*']
  cpu_ticks : false



#================================ General =====================================

# The name of the shipper that publishes the network data. It can be used to group
# all the transactions sent by a single shipper in the web interface.
#name:

# The tags of the shipper are included in their own field with each
# transaction published.
#tags: ["service-X", "web-tier"]

# Optional fields that you can specify to add additional information to the
# output.
#fields:
#  env: staging

#================================ Outputs =====================================

# Configure what outputs to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
# Multiple outputs may be used.

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  #hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

  # Optional protocol and basic auth credentials.
  #protocol: "https"
  #username: "elastic"
  #password: "changeme"

#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
#output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["127.0.0.1:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"]

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: "/etc/pki/client/cert.pem"

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: "/etc/pki/client/cert.key"

#================================ Logging =====================================

# Sets log level. The default log level is info.
# Available log levels are: critical, error, warning, info, debug
logging.level: debug
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
      }
    }




output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        sniffing => true
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      }
    }
```

I am running metricbeat service but can’t get the index in Kibana (localhost:5601). What is the problem, I can't figure it out ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to send data to your logstash using the elasticsearch output of metricbeat.

In fact, in your `metricbeat.yml` you have this line uncommented:

```
output.elasticsearch:
```

and this one commented:

```
#output.logstash:
```

If you toggle the comments in both lines it could work.